# Get-EventLog - easily filter by 'today'?

Tags: date, powershell, datetime

I want to quickly check for events that happened today (that is: anything from midnight onwards); is there 'today' alias/built-in in Powershell to help out with this ?

I'm currently doing something like this:

```
get-eventlog system  -source "disk" -after ([datetime] '01/01/2015')
```

But of course I keep having to change the date string.

[ Also: that datetime constructor appears to insist on a US date-format (mm/dd/yyyy) only - despite the fact that my Windows Locale is UK ?]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today(v=vs.110).aspx) class has a static Property `Today` which will return exactly what you need:

```
get-eventlog system  -source "disk" -after ([datetime]::Today)
```

Comment: Great- yup works ! I'll accept when the StackOverFlow timer lets me ! (You were just *too* quick to answer it seems!)