# How to register an event for 'get-eventlog'?

Tags: powershell, event-log

I need to watch for specific errors in my Windows 7 event log - is there is a one-liner to do this ?

So: for example - I am watching out for 'disk' errors; so I can get the latest events by doing something like:

```
get-eventlog system  -source "disk" -after ([datetime]::Today)
```

(This is the answer from another Post in fact:  [Get-EventLog - easily filter by 'today'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36550585/get-eventlog-easily-filter-by-today) )

But obviously I have to keep running this to keep on top of any alerts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no one-liner. But instead of **polling** the EventLog, you could use the `System.Diagnostic.EventLog` class and register to the `EntryWritten` **event** using the [Register-ObjectEvent](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135244) cmdlet.

Here an example where I register to the application log and just output the message in the callback:

```
$eventLog = New-Object System.Diagnostics.EventLog "application"
$eventLog.EnableRaisingEvents = $true
$job = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $eventLog -EventName "EntryWritten" -Action { Write-Host ($eventArgs.Entry.Message) } 
Receive-Job $job
```

You can now test the callback using:

```
$eventLog.Source = "test"
$eventLog.WriteEntry("test")
```

Which will output `test` to the console.

Comment: great: I tested this by launching WORD - and my console filled up with stuff as soon as it started - this is my accepted answer since it saves me having to loop manually (but I'll be stealing bits of Richard Slater's answer as well :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's not strictly a one-liner but what you are after is to `tail` the event log, you can do this with PowerShell with the following commands:

```
$lastCheck = [DateTime]::Now.Date
while ($true) {
  Get-EventLog System -Source "disk" -After $lastCheck -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  $lastCheck = [DateTime]::Now.DateTime
  Start-Sleep 1
}
```

If you take this a step further and wrap it in a function, *then* it becomes a one-liner:

```
function Tail-EventLog ($source) {
  $lastCheck = [DateTime]::Now.Date
  while ($true) {
    Get-EventLog System -Source $source -After $lastCheck -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $lastCheck = [DateTime]::Now.DateTime
    Start-Sleep 1
  }
}
```

Which you can execute with:

```
Tail-EventLog "disk"
```

You can put this in your [PowerShell Profile](http://www.howtogeek.com/50236/customizing-your-powershell-profile/) to make sure it is always available to you.

Comment: That works: actually I changed the 'Now.Date' to 'Now.DateTime' - which I think works better - thanks ! (So is there no 'Register-Event' type cmdlet for this sort of thing do you know ?)

Comment: Oh : and thanks for the updated function-version of this.

Comment: Good Call - Copy Paste Fail!

Comment: ... and no there isn't a mechanism to "observe" the event logs and callback a function when a new event appears.  PowerShell isn't really an Async language so that paradigm isn't well catered for.

Comment: You can still do it - check my answer.

Comment: That's a fantastic solution, far more effective than my own.